# SQL logic error or missing database on release mode and not in debug mode

Tags: c#, system.data.sqlite

I have an application in c# which works fine in debug mode in VS 2013 but when I try to run it in release mode I receive the next message:

[image]

in the next file I have my connection string:

[image]

why does it work in debug mode and I get an exception in release mode? 
might be the path?

Comment: Details on the exception?

Comment: well.. does your table exists (tbCEEmployee)? Is your sql user using the good database?